# Is it possible to shorten the XDeclaration of an XDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, quickbooks-online

I'm adding an XDeclaration to my Xdocument as follows:

```
XDocument xml = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes")
```

This gives me the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

I'm building XML for Quickbooks Merchant Services so I only need:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to convert it to a string anyway, so I did a replace on the text I didn't want left in there:

```
string xmlString = xml.Declaration.ToString() + "\n" + xml.ToString();
xmlString = xmlString.Replace(@" encoding=""utf-8"" standalone=""yes""", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using custom `StringWriter` which doesn't provide any encoding, for example :

```
public class StringWriterNoEncoding : StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}
```

Then use `StringWriterNoEncoding` to print the XML :

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "", ""), new XElement("Root"));
var sw = new StringWriterNoEncoding();
xdoc.Save(sw);
Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
//above will print :
//<?xml version="1.0"?>
//<Root />
```

Answer (score 2):

Set encoding and standalone to null:

```
XDocument xml = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", null, null)
```

will give

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
void Main() {
    XDocument xml = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", ""), new XElement("Root"));
    var sw = new UTF8StringWriter();
    xml.Save(sw);
    Console.WriteLine(sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString());    
}

private class UTF8StringWriter : StringWriter {
    public override Encoding Encoding { get { return Encoding.UTF8; } }
}
```

Output:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root />`